# What is the recommended way to connect to Azure SQL from on-prem service(WebAPI)?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Do I need to use SQL authentication or Azure AAD authentication? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134034/how-to-connect-azure-web-app-to-azure-sql-database (Substitute your web app/API for Azure and it's similar)

Answer (score 0):

Azure AAD authentication is an alternative to SQL Authentication. 
It is useful when you want to manage all user accounts including database users from central location (AD).