# Which service should I use to Deploy a Windows App (Conternized) to Azure Cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Azure and I have a requirement to deploy Windows Desktop Application that runs on IIS server and also has a SQL DB that needs to be deployed to Azure Cloud to prove that Elasticity is possible, as we are having our own DataCenters and we wanted to move to cloud.

1. I figured we need to create Docker Image for App Server and DB and this app will run only in Windows IIS server.
2. We have Azure SQL DB service, but what should be my approach for Windows App.

Does Azure provide any service that can help me achieve my requirement?

Any guidance is appreciated. I wanted to get started in right direction.

Comment: *Windows Desktop Application that runs on IIS* huh, a desktop application on a web server? What is it? a Winforms/WPF app or a website?

Answer (score -2):

Not easy to guess what you need exactly when you say "Desktop App on IIS" :( but first things who come in my mind as an Azure user :

- "App who run on IIS" -> Asp.Net on [Azure WebApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/) for example
- "Azure SQL DB service, what should be my approach for Windows App" -> connect your WebApp to your Azure SQL DB which you can reach technically following [this link for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134034/how-to-connect-azure-web-app-to-azure-sql-database), but I would recommend you to first get a better understanding of WebApp if it's a WebApp that you need and how use the connection string that you set on the Azure Portal in the app that you deploy on Azure.

A quick look on this Azure resources should tell you if it can match your goal.

Comment: There is nothing objective about this answer. Web Apps: Do you know whether the app will work within the sandbox environment? If not, this is not a viable solution. And the OP already asked about containers (but again, there's no way to answer, aside from with an opinion, as we know nothing about the app). As for the database: the OP already uses a SQL DB. It's unclear what, specifically, they are looking at doing, beyond current usage

Comment: @DavidMakogon This was advice based on the minimum we know !!! my answer was enough : i said for each of the suggestion that it was an example and i link the documentation ! it was a starting point for someone who start Azure from zero, like "on which direction should i search ?" There is nothing objective in YOUR answer who's just negative and brings exactly nothing ! Why you don't show us the good answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer to be given here. The question is too broad (and no code either - just a generic mention of IIS and SQL DB). There's a fine line with Stack Overflow. A generic question such as "which service to use" is typically going to be too broad. With no specific answer possible. I won't answer this type of question, as there is simply no objective way to do it. Note: there is lots of documentation available explaining the various features and options in Azure, at a high level, which is typically a great place to start.

Comment: It's just that I think that it would be better sometimes to give a generic answer, it's better than just send people back to where they come with no more than a "you are not enough specific". That just give the worst image possible to new user, and more, this time, also to a new  contributor. One more time, saying "go there, search here, learn this" is better than just "no specific", else we should make a new tag or change the existing Azure tag to AzureOnlySpecificQuestion.